# Quais são os padrões de projeto referentes a ServiceProvider e ServiceContainer, usados no Laravel e Symfony?

Tags: laravel, design-pattern, symfony-2

Nos frameworks `Laravel 4 ou 5` e `Symfony`, percebo que existe duas classe que são essenciais para o funcionamento de todo o sistema: ServiceContainer e ServiceProvider.

Parece se tratar de uma forma de você armazenar em um container instâncias de classes com suas dependências já resolvidas, ou então uma `Closure`, que carrega as definições dessas dependências (acho que esses são os "serviços"). Assim, ao chamar um determinado serviço (que está no container), estamos chamando de maneira mais simplificada a instância da classe desejada.

Vou dar um exemplo do que estou querendo dizer, porém esse exemplo não há ServiceProvider (provedor de serviço), mas apenas a utilização do service container:

## Service Container

```
 class UrlGenerator
 {
      public function __construct(Request $request)
      {}
 }

 class Request{
       public function __construct(Header $header){}
 }

 class Header{}
```

Aí vem a definição das instâncias no container.

```
 $app->bind('header', function () { 

    return new Header;
 });

 $app->bind('request', function ($app)
 {
      return new Request($app->getService('header'));
 });

 $app->bind('url', function ($app)
 {
      return new UrlGenerator($app->getService('request'));
 });
```

Assim, se precisassemos de utilizar a classe `UrlGenerator`, ao invés de sempre ter que passar como parâmetro da mesma uma instância de `Request`, poderíamos fazer isso:

```
 $app->getService('url')->getRoot();
```

## Service Provider

Já no outro caso, temos o `ServiceProvider`, que poderia fazer o seguinte:

```
class UrlGeneratorProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
     public function register()
     {
           $this->app->bind('url', function ($app) { /** **/});
     }
}
```

Aí no caso, seria chamado pelo `ServiceContainer`

```
$app->setService(new UrlGeneratorProvider);
```

Nesse caso, entendo que o `UrlGeneratorProvider`, passa a definição necessárias para criar o serviço, simplesmente através do método `register`.

Achei interessante esse padrão e gostaria de saber qual é o nome deles. Pois em alguns frameworks as classes responsáveis por conter todos os serviços são chamadas de `Application`, `Container` ou `ServiceContainer`. Já no caso dos "provedores de serviço" os nomes são sempre esses, na maioria das vezes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Desenvolvi, no final do ano passado (2015), o meu TCC sobre uma comparação entre os Frameworks Codeigniter e Laravel 5, e sobre a utilização de padrões de projeto em seus desenvolvimentos. Por isso, estudei bastante sobre os Design Patterns utilizados no Laravel. E uma das coisas que mais gostei no Laravel é justamente essa parte do ServiceProvider.

Você explicou direitinho o funcionamento do **ServiceProvider** e do **ServiceContainer**. Esses mecanismos estão de acordo com o padrão de **INVERSÃO DE CONTROLE ou (IoC)**. Este padrão é utilizado para diminuir o acoplamento das classes.

Veja abaixo uma classe simples que grava uma venda de um produto e logo em seguida deve gravar um log.

```
public class VendaDeProduto { 
    public function vendeProduto($produto) { 
        //Todo o código para a venda do produto... 
        $log = new Log("Arquivo.txt"); 
        $log->grava($produto); 
    } 
}
```

Observe que a classes **VendaDeProduto** tem a responsabilidade de instanciar a classes de Log. 
Mas o que acontece quando se eu precisar alterar o nome do arquivo de log para  "ArquivoLog.txt"?

Será necessário editar todas as classes que instanciam a classe Log e realizar está alteração. 
Por este motivo é necessário retirar da classe **VendaDeProduto** o controle dessa instanciação.

Existem algumas formas de realizar a **Inversão de Controle**, uma delas é utilizando a **Injeção de Dependência**. Veja o código abaixo:

```
public class VendaDeProduto { 
    private $log; 
    public function vendaDeProduto(Log $logVenda) { 
        $this->log = $logVenda; 
    } 
    public function vendeProduto($produto) { 
        //Todo o código para a venda do produto... 
        $log->grava($produto); 
    } 
}
```

A classe **VendaDeProduto** precisa da classe **Log** para criar um Log mas neste código a classe VendaDeProduto recebeu uma instância da classe Log! Ou seja, agora ela não se preocupa mais com a criação da classe Log e simplesmente a usa.

Agora está a melhor coisa do Laravél (na minha opnial), o ServiceProvider. Veja abaixo uma das várias formas de implementar o serviço Log:

```
class LogProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
     public function register()
     {
           $this->app->bind('Log', function ($app) { 
                return new LogFile("ArquivoLog.txt");
           });
     }
}
```

Observe que na verdade quando utilizamos o serviço **Log**, estamos na verdade utilizando uma instancia da classe **LogFile**. Se por um acaso, eu quiser parar de gravar o log em arquivo texto e comece a gravar em um banco de dados, eu posso simplesmente alterar a implementação do meu serviço, passando a instanciar a classe **LogEmBanco**.

```
$this->app->bind('Log', function ($app) { 
    return new LogEmBanco("MySQL");
});
```

E como uma mágica, todos os meus logs começam a ser gravados no banco MySQL, sem alterar nenhuma outra classe.

Resumindo sua pergunta, pesquise sobre **INVERSÃO DE CONTROLE** e **INJEÇÃO DE DEPENDÊNCIA**.

De uma lida neste link, aqui tem tudo que eu escrevi e um pouco mais.

http://www.devmedia.com.br/inversao-de-controle-x-injecao-de-dependencia/18763