# É possível definir uma classe dentro de uma array em versões anteriores do PHP 7?

Tags: php

É possível? Se sim, como? No PHP 7 é possível criar classes anônimas, que tem possibilidade de serem definidas em qualquer variável/propriedade, mas não sei se é possível fazer isso nas versões anteriores, até porque não sou muito ativo... em PHP.

Eu quero fazer algo como isso:

```
$arr = array("class" => new class() {});
```

Daí eu poderia construir minha classe dessa forma:

```
new $arr->class(/* ... */);
```

**P.S:** Eu estava pensando em fazer isso porque estou convertendo o código de uma library, porém não precisava fazer isso bem necessariamente. A situação: o código é escrito em JavaScript e faz uso de classes, exemplo:

```
/**
 * Representa uma tabela em Lua.
 * @param {Object} obj Valores iniciais para montar na nova tabela.
 */
shine.Table = function(obj) {/* ... */};
```

Que seria construída assim:

```
new shine.Table;
```

O problema de converter esse código para PHP é por eu não achar possibilidades de implementar uma classe dentro de uma array (ou objeto). A intenção é executar Lua no PHP, então adotar Lua em um projeto, que pode ser programado por alguém e executado ao *lado* do servidor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Talvez haja confusões de termos aí. Se você está falando das versões do PHP anteriores ao PHP 7 (atualmente PHP 5.6 para baixo), não existe  o recurso das *Classes Anônimas*.

Na verdade, não confunda "instância de classes" com "declaração/definição de classes".

*Definição ou Declaração* é o ato de você escrever a classe. A *instância da classe* trata do objeto, da utilização da classe através do operador `new`.

Se a pergunta é no sentido de ser possível guardar instâncias de classes (mais conhecido como "objeto") dentro de um `array`, sim, é possível.

Exemplo PHP 5:

```
class User {
      public $name = 'Wallace';
}

$arr = [];

$arr['user'] = new User;

// OU

$arr = ['user' => new User];

echo $arr['user']->name; // Obtendo o valor
```

Como dito anteriormente, em versões anteriores ao PHP 7, não existem classes anônimas, portanto, não é possível utilizar esse recurso antes do PHP 7. Mas em relação às instâncias de classes, é possível guardar seus valores em um índice de um `array` tranquilamente, desde que você pode declará-la.

## Atualização

Após a atualização da pergunta, percebi que o Autor queria fazer uma espécie de conteiner/repostório com nomes de classes.

É possível fazer isso em PHP devido a maneira dinâmica oferecida pela linguagem de tratar os dados.

**Referenciando as classes pelo seu nome, através de uma `string`**:

No php é possível instanciar uma classe apenas sabendo seu nome. Se você tem uma string, por exemplo, com o nome da classe, é possível instanciá-la.

```
class TaskClass {
       public function run() {}
}

$repository = [
   'task' => 'TaskClass',
];


$task = new $repository['task'];

$task->run();
```

**Operador de resolução de escopo combinado com `::class`**

No PHP, nas versões anteriores ao 5.5, é possível utilizar `::class` para resolver o nome de uma classe.

Veja:

```
 use App\Project\Task;

 $repository = [

     'task' => \App\Project\Task::class, // nome completo,

     'another_task' => Task::class,
 ];


 $task = new $repository['task'];

 $task2 = new $repository['task'];

 get_class($task); // App\Project\Task(object)

 get_class($task2); // App\Project\Task(object) # esse é o nome real
```

Em alguns casos, se precisar pode usar o padrão descrito nessa pergunta:

[Quais são os padrões de projeto referentes a ServiceProvider e ServiceContainer, usados no Laravel e Symfony?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/116120/quais-s%C3%A3o-os-padr%C3%B5es-de-projeto-referentes-a-serviceprovider-e-servicecontainer)

Onde você utiliza `Closures` (funções anônimas) para amarrar a lógica de instanciação da classe. É claro que nesse caso, trata-se de algo mais complexo, mas que poderia ser exemplificado da seguinte forma:

```
 $repository = [

     'task' => function ($parametro) {
           return new Task($parametro);
      }
 ];


 $task = $repository['task'](); // chama como se faz com as funções
```

Comment: Ótima resposta.

Answer (score 5):

No código que postou está instanciando uma [classe anônima](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php).

Classes anônimas foram introduzidas no PHP7.

Independente de estar usando array, não funcionará em versões inferiores.

Abaixos duas opções, distintas uma da outra:

## Usando stdClass

O objetivo final não está claro, portanto, talvez seja útil saber que pode instanciar um stdClass

```
$arr = array("class" => (object)array('foo') = 'bar');

print_r($arr);
// ou
echo $arr['class']->foo;
```

## Nome da classe a partir de uma variável

```
class Foo
{

}

$clss = 'Foo';
$foo = new $clss();
```

<sub>Obviamente nesse caso a classe já deve existir antes de ser invocada.</sub>

Comment: Boa Daniel, até esqueci do `stdClass`

Comment: Parece que você não usou `stdClass`, ou estou confundindo? Se eu usasse `stdClass` puramente seria possível construir `$arr->class` com `new`, por exemplo: `new $arr->class(...);`? Espero que eu não esteja errando.

Comment: @TheProHands ele usou o `stdClass` sim. Quando você faz um `cast` (conversão de tipos) em php para `object`, você transforma um `array` no `stdClass`.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters A diferença é que dá para definir as propriedades declarando uma array, depois convertendo a mesma para um objeto. Obrigado pela resposta dos 2

Comment: Por acaso quer saber como instanciar uma classe a partir de uma variável? Pois há indícios disso na pergunta e nesse seu comentário.

Comment: @TheProHands dei uma melhorada na minha resposta após a sua atualização. Dá uma olhadinha :D