# O que é Acoplamento entre Classes?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, terminologia, independente-de-linguagem

Estava lendo esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/124157/27190) em relação aos padrões de projeto referentes a ServiceProvider e ServiceContainer, entretanto, o AR [Euler01](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/14374/euler01) citou um padrão que menciona o acoplamento entre classes, e foi neste ponto que me gerou uma dúvida.

Este termo:

**Acoplamento entre Classes**

---

## Dúvidas

Eu gostaria de saber o que é acoplamento entre classes?

*<sup>Se possível, eu gostaria de exemplos de ilustração em PHP ou C#, mas sinta-se a vontade para dar exemplos em outras linguagens.</sup>*

Comment: Relacionada:[Qual a definição do termo acoplamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11098/qual-a-defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-termo-acoplamento)

Comment: Relacionada²:[O que são os conceitos de coesão e acoplamento?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/28595)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que são os conceitos de coesão e acoplamento?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81314/o-que-s%c3%a3o-os-conceitos-de-coes%c3%a3o-e-acoplamento)

Comment: @Edilson eu li os posts desses dois links relacionados. Não responde diretamente a resposta, explica o conceito mas não mostra na pratica o acoplamento entre as classes. E na minha pergunta eu gostaria de respostas com exemplos práticos.

Comment: Downvoter seria interessante vc me dizer onde eu posso melhorar a pergunta. E não se preocupe eu não vou te esquartejar com minhas garras :P

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Em engenharia de software, o acoplamento é uma métrica que define o grau de inter-dependência entre os elementos de um modulo. Poderíamos resumir em uma palavra: Dependência, ou seja, o acoplamento é o grau de dependência em que um artefato se relaciona com outro, considere um artefato como qualquer "coisa" que faça parte do produto final no ambiente de desenvolvimento (Um framework, um objeto, uma classe, etc).
No contexto de classes, acoplamento refere-se ao modo como diferentes classes se conectam umas com as outras.

**Acoplamento fraco ou baixo acoplamento**: os componentes de um sistema são interconectados de modo que um dependa do outro o mínimo possível.

**Acoplamento forte ou alto acoplamento**: Os componentes são interconectados de uma forma tão dependente que é praticamente impossível alterar um deles sem causar efeitos colaterais em todo ou em grande parte do sistema.

**Classes fortemente acopladas** contém um grande número de interações e dependências, enquanto que nas **classes com acoplamento fraco**, ocorre o oposto, em que as dependências entre as classes são resolvidas através de interfaces públicas bem definidas, reduzindo o máximo possível as dependências diretas.

Um dos desenvolvedores da extinta SUN, em um forum, postou o seguinte texto (ligeiramente adaptado para o contexto dessa resposta) em uma discussão sobre acoplamento:

> Legos, aqueles brinquedos de encaixar, seriam considerados fracamente
>   acoplados, porque você poderia simplesmente juntar as peças e
>   construir qualquer sistema que quiser. No entanto um quebra-cabeças
>   tem peças que são **fortemente** acopladas. Você não pode pegar um
>   pedaço de um quebra-cabeça (sistema) e encaixá-lo em um quebra-cabeça
>   diferente, porque o sistema (quebra-cabeça) é muito dependente das
>   peças que foram construídas especificamente para aquele design
>   particular. Os legos são construídos de uma forma mais genérica de
>   forma que permita que com as mesmas peças que voce constroi uma casa
>   eu possa construir um carro.

É praticamente impossível desenvolver software sem acoplamento nenhum, mas é desejável que o acoplamento seja o mais fraco possível.

Vou dar um exemplo em python porque é a linguagem que estou envolvido no momento, claro que esse exemplo apresenta um absurdo somente para evidenciar o problema do acoplamento.

```
class A:
    def get_hello():
        b = B
        return b

class B:
    def hello():
        print ('Hello World!')            

>>>> A.get_hello().hello()                   
>>>> Hello World!
```

Veja que para executar hello() é chamado um método de um objeto retornado por outro método, o método hello() é chamado pelo metodo get_hello(), isso é péssimo porque aumenta o acoplamento entre as classes tornando difícil a manutenção, uma vez que se uma delas for substituída ou refatorada pagar-se-a o preço de efeitos colaterais.

No contexto do python é possível elucidar um pouco mais nesse exemplo:

```
def func(obj):
    obj.method1()  # Ok
    obj.method1().method2() # Bad
```

Nesse exemplo, o parâmetro passado é um objeto que tem um método (method1), que, por sua vez, tem embutido um segundo método, depender dessa chamada nessa classe é que configura o problema do acoplamento.

> Um boa prática para um desenvolvedor quando está construindo uma
>   classe é se perguntar: Estou concebendo algo mais parecido com o lego
>   o com um quebra-cabeças?

Como mencionado nos comentários, sugiro que estude também o conceito de coesão. O acoplamento refere-se a como os artefatos se relacionam uns  com os outros e a coesão refere-se à forma de como os componentes internos de um artefato se relacionam.

Quanto maior a coesão, menor será o nível de acoplamento e melhor será o design do software.

Comment: Então quando mais coesa e menos acoplada o projeto mais classes ele terá?
Visto que precisa-se criar abstrações para poder ser feito as extensões..

Comment: Vai depender do projeto, mas acredito que na maioria a resposta seja sim, mas a diferença crucial é que as classes serão menores, enxutas e especializadas, além do fato de que para conseguir coesão vc tera que ter uma visão muito mais clara do projeto como um todo e de como as partes se conectam, dá trabalho para "conceber", mas a manutenção fica muito mais fácil.

Comment: @Sidon o fato de eu utilizar frameworks já ajuda a manter um acoplamento baixo entre classes?

Comment: Provavelmente sim, todo FW que se preze deve ter isso no topo das prioridades, mas é claro  que vc é que tem que cuidar disso na parte que voce desenvolve.