# Qual o critério do Java em ter em alguns casos, uma classe na sua API e em outros casos uma interface?

Tags: java, api, classes, engenharia-de-software, interface

A API Java é imensa, porém algumas funcionalidades pre-definidas nela são implementadas através de uma classe e outras funcionalidade através de uma interface.

Qual o critério utilizado pelo Java para escolher uma ou outra?

Comment: Tem a ver com o acoplamento[¹](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/193420/o-que-%c3%a9-acoplamento-entre-classes),[²](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81314/o-que-s%c3%a3o-os-conceitos-de-coes%c3%a3o-e-acoplamento?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 5):

Basicamente o mesmo critério que qualquer pessoa deveria adotar quando cria uma aplicação Java ou o critério a ser adotado em outra linguagem, esse conceito é universal e deveria não depender da tecnologia.

Claro que pode haver uma certa subjetividade na escolha, mas entre essas duas coisas é uma questão de se encaixar mais com o objetivo, de ser naturalmente uma coisa ou outra.

O critério poderia ser mais específico se fosse só sobre o Java escolher se algo entrará na sua API padrão.

Então primeiro precisa entender bem o que é cada coisa, assim fica fácil definir, ou seja, eles escolhem isso porque sabem para que serve cada mecanismo e sabem o que estão fazendo em específico e que será mais adequado usar um ou outro.

Inclusive pode ser melhor outra coisa. E hoje interfaces são mais modernas. E em breve haverá as "classes" por valor, que não são consideradas classes mais, e já está começando ter as classes pré-implementadas (os *records*). Então a decisão vai ficando mais difícil, mas não vou falar sobre esses mecanismos que não estão na pergunta.

Por ora, aprenda:

- [Diferença classe e interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136404/101)
- [Como e quando usar Interface?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107524/101)
- [Em orientação a objetos, por que interfaces são úteis?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2913/101)
- [Programar voltado para interface e não para a implementação, por quê?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101)
- [O que é e para que serve uma classe abstrata?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87423/101)
- [Interface ou Abstract?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35317/101)
- [Devo estender de uma classe abstrata ou de uma concreta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89236/101)
- [Classe Abstrata X Interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3603/101)
- [Java não possui herança múltipla?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22718/101)
- [Por que os métodos implementados de uma interface não podem ser privados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58891/101)
- [Utilizar muitas interfaces é uma má prática de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30399/101)
- [O que é herança de tipo e estado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190140/101)
- [ArrayList x List](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73633/101)
- [Em OOP, uma interface pode ter atributos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89894/101)
- [Interface Java 8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90168/101)
- [Qual o uso de default interface methods?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/235460/101)
- [Quando usar record ou class no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/481890/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre Struct e Class?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101)
- [Devo utilizar classe abstrata ou interface?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/166530/101)
- [Quando devo usar Herança, Classe Abstrata, Interface ou um Trait?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73449/101)
- [É correto dar maior preferência a composição do que herança?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11378/101)
- [O que são os conceitos de coesão e acoplamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre uma classe e um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/101)

Isso é só a ponta do *iceberg* para ajudar a escolha, tem que entender tudo sobre computação, como se faz o *design* de código.

Então, em resumo, interfaces são usadas para **definir contratos** que outros tipos terão, são para definir quais capacidades um objeto terá e que o código poderá acessá-lo de forma "segura", enquanto que a classe **define um objeto**, o que pode incluir interfaces. Precisa ver o que está fazendo ali, é para definir um objeto ou um contrato que objetos terão? Essa é a pergunta básica a se fazer.